# Query rules and REST

Tags: search-results, rest, ranking

Is it possible to create a query rule and have the condition match a keyword in a complex KQL query? For example the following query is being issued from a third party application using the REST endpoint. Could we create a query rule that would fire on the query below for the condition "query contains programmer"?

querytext="(programmer)(Location:California)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, create the rule and use:

- Advanced Query Text Match
- Query contains one of these phrases (semi-colon separated) = Programmer

On a side note you know you can also configure "Query Client Types" and give the developers an ID to pass with their query for logging and performance tuning.

Comment: I've created a rule that matches fine when only a simple keyword query is performed. However when i add any KQL syntax the rule doesn't fire. Thanks for the tip on client types!

Comment: Over on Search Explained Mikael Svenson pointed out ""Every query condition becomes false if the query is not a simple keyword query, such as if it has *quotes*, property filters, parentheses, or special operators. " this may be causing your Query rule to fail.

Comment: So I guess it's not possible to use query rules for more advanced queries? That's sad news...

Comment: The problem was with the syntax of my query. Once I corrected the query the rule fired successfully. I ended up breaking the query up and using the QueryTemplate for the property filtering.